# Gulp: avoid intermediate files when compiling mustache

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mustache

I have the following directory structure in my repos:

```
src
  some-project
    some-file.html
    some-file.yml
  other-project
    foo.html
    foo.yml
    bar.html
    bar.yml
  stylesheet.css

dist
  some-project
    some-file.html
    some-file.yml
  other-project
    foo.html
    foo.yml
    bar.html
    bar.yml
```

I have a gulp task that takes the styles in any stylesheet added by an html file in the /src folder and automatically inlines them in the html (these are emails). The yml are meta-information used when sending data.

Now I want to add mustache templating to my HTML. The data for the templates is going to be in the yml files. The issue I have is that the gulp-mustache plugin takes a stream for its template input and an object in parameter for its data.

```
gulp.task('build', () => {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(mustache(data)) // I don't have the data!
    .pipe(inlineCss({
      removeStyleTags: false
    }))
    .pipe(prefix(BASE_URL, [ { match: "img[src]", attr: "src"} ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

I have another task that can compile YML to JSON, but I was trying to avoid creating temporary files since it defeats the whole point of having gulp's virtual file streams. Besides, it doesn't solve the problem that I have two tasks and two gulp pipes, I can't pass the content of one file to the mustache function. Is there something I'm missing?

It seems like a very simple task and I've searched for hours without any progress. Isn't there a way for gulp to read files per pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first thing I notice is that you're not returning anything in your Gulp task, which prevents Gulp from knowing when your task finished.

Since the task itself is asynchronous and Gulp supports tasks [returning a Promise](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#return-a-promise) that will signal completion when it resolves, you could do something like that, using [node-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-yaml) package which returns a Promise too:

```
const yaml = require('node-yaml')

gulp.task('build', () => {
  return yaml.read('my-data.yml').then(data =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(mustache(data))
        // ...
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .on('end', resolve)
    });
  );
});
```

Or simply using [callbacks](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#accept-a-callback):

```
gulp.task('build', callback => {
  return yaml.read('my-data.yml', data => {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
      .pipe(mustache(data))
      // ...
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
      .on('end', callback)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be trying this out tomorrow but it makes a lot of sense. I'm not new to JS, but I'm new to the node way of doing things.

Comment: Ah, this won't exactly as-is. It's a push in the right direction I think, but I need to pipe the right yaml in the right html.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I see! This might be a bit trickier indeed. So you  have 1 yaml file for 1 mustache template? I invite you to open a separate question where you describe that schema in more details. Even though we often want to do as much as possible by ourselves, remember to be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. I probably shouldn't have asked the question like this.